# Java 8 Stream filter using list as condition

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Hello I'm beginner when it comes to Java 8 so please be patient for me :)

I have a method that returns custom list of objects. What I need to do: I have got a list of `disabledPaymentTypesStrings` - and I don't know how many elements it has got. How can I change my code in order to not write every condition like `!paymentType.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(disabledPaymentTypesStrings.get(1))`? I would like to have somehow my whole list "disabledPaymentTypesStrings" placed here as a condition but I have no idea how to do that. Please give me some hints or advices :)

```
private List<PaymentType> listOfPaymentTypesForChangePayment(OrderPaymentTypeParameters paymentTypeParameters) {

        List<String> disabledPaymentTypesStrings = newArrayList(Splitter.on(COMMA).split(systemUtils.getChangePaymentTypeDisabled()));

        return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters).stream()
            .filter(paymentType ->
                !paymentType.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(disabledPaymentTypesStrings.get(0)) &&
                !paymentType.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(disabledPaymentTypesStrings.get(1)) &&
                !paymentType.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(disabledPaymentTypesStrings.get(2)))
            .collect(toList());
    }
```

Comment: Consider representing your payment types as enums rather than strings. Use a set instead of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stream approach could consist in the `filter()` to stream the List of String and keep `PaymentType` elements where `paymentType.getName()` don't match with any elements of the List of String :

```
return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters)
        .stream()
        .filter(paymentType -> disabledPaymentTypesStrings.stream()
               .allMatch(ref -> !ref.equalsIgnoreCase(paymentType.getName())))
        .collect(toList());
```

But you could also compare `String`s  by using the same case. For example lowercase.  It will simplify the filtering.

You can convert the reference list elements to lowercase  :

```
List<String> disabledPaymentTypesStrings = newArrayList(Splitter.on(COMMA).split(systemUtils.getChangePaymentTypeDisabled()))
 .stream()
 .map(String::toLowerCase)
 .collect(toList());
```

And you can so use `List.contains()` in the `filter()` :

```
return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters)
    .stream()
    .filter(paymentType -> !disabledPaymentTypesStrings.contains(paymentType.getName().toLowerCase()))
    .collect(toList());
```

Note that for big lists, using a `Set` would be more efficient.

Comment: A note for the sake of completness: Converting `disabledPaymentTypesStrings` to a `List` and calling `contains` on it implies that `disabledPaymentTypesStrings` does have 3 elements. Regarding the code in the question there could be more than 3 elements but only the first 3 are compared. And a second note: Like @RealSkeptic suggests in his comment, using a `Set` is more suitable when calling `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains()`. But you have to think about case sensitivity ignoring

```
private List<PaymentType> listOfPaymentTypesForChangePayment(OrderPaymentTypeParameters paymentTypeParameters) {

            List<String> disabledPaymentTypesStrings = newArrayList(Splitter.on(COMMA).split(systemUtils.getChangePaymentTypeDisabled()));

            return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters).stream()
                .filter(paymentType -> !disabledPaymentTypesStrings.contains(paymentType)
                .collect(toList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the steps need to have values in common case(either in uppercase or in lowercase, I preferred lowercase)

```
List<String> disabledPaymentTypesStringsLowerCase = newArrayList(Splitter.on(COMMA).split(systemUtils.getChangePaymentTypeDisabled()))
 .stream()
 .map(String::toLowerCase)
 .collect(toList());

return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters)
    .stream()
    .map(paymentType -> paymentType.getName())
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .filter(disabledPaymentTypesStrings::contains)
    .collect(toList());
```

This **code can further be refactored if paymentType class is known,** assuming class of paymentType is **PaymentType** code would look like below,

```
return paymentTypeSelector.availablePaymentTypesForChangePayment(paymentTypeParameters)
    .stream()
    .map(PaymentType::getName)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .filter(disabledPaymentTypesStrings::contains)
    .collect(toList());
```